# Reading YAML with Ruby, unexpected return type

Tags: arrays, ruby, count, yaml

I have a YAML file that has a couple keys with multiple values and a couple with one value:

```
inbox:
  paul: 'PHILADELPHIA-RO-ADMIN'
  tanny: 'PA-C-INDIANA-ADMIN'
  mary:
          - 'MD-C-LAUREL-ADMIN'
          - 'MD-E-BALTIMORE-ADMIN'
          - 'MD-R1-CAMBRIDGE-ADMIN'
          - 'MD-R2-BELAIR-ADMIN'
          - 'MD-R4-LAUREL-ADMIN'
          - 'MD-R5-HAGERSTWN-ADMIN'
  mike:
          - 'VA-E-Richmond-Admin'
          - 'VA-Richmond-Admin'
          - 'VA-Manassas-Admin'
          - 'VA-Norfolk-Admin'
          - 'VA-Roanoke-Admin'
          - 'VA-Verona-Admin'
```

What I'm attempting to do is if the key has more than one value output the key has more than one value, however if the key has only one value, only output that value. I'm trying to use the `Array.count` function to do this, I've come across an issue where if the Array has only one value it counts amount of characters inside of the key, for example:

```
require 'yaml'

POC = YAML.load_file('test.yml')

def get_poc(name)

  data = POC['inbox'][name.downcase]
  puts data.count
  if data.count == 1
    POC['inbox'][name]
  else
    puts "Multiple inboxes found for #{name.capitalize.chomp}"
    data.each.with_index(1) do |str, i|
      puts "#{i}. #{str}"
    end
    puts 'One of the above inboxes is the correct inbox for this ticket.'
  end
end
```

When this is run in IRB:

```
irb(main):020:0> get_poc('mary')
6
Multiple inboxes found for Mary
1. MD-C-LAUREL-ADMIN
2. MD-E-BALTIMORE-ADMIN
3. MD-R1-CAMBRIDGE-ADMIN
4. MD-R2-BELAIR-ADMIN
5. MD-R4-LAUREL-ADMIN
6. MD-R5-HAGERSTWN-ADMIN
One of the above inboxes is the correct inbox for this ticket.
=> nil
irb(main):021:0> get_poc('paul')
21
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1+)
        from (irb):10:in `count'
        from (irb):10:in `get_poc'
        from (irb):21
        from C:/Ruby23/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
irb(main):022:0>
```

It seems that it works for multiple values, however when there's only one value given it seems to actually count the full length of the value by characters.

I've also tried using the `Array.length` method:

```
require 'yaml'

    POC = YAML.load_file('test.yml')

    def get_poc(name)

      data = POC['inbox'][name.downcase]
      puts data.length
      if data.length == 1
        POC['inbox'][name]
      else
        puts "Multiple inboxes found for #{name.capitalize.chomp}"
        data.each.with_index(1) do |str, i|
          puts "#{i}. #{str}"
        end
        puts 'One of the above inboxes is the correct inbox for this ticket.'
      end
    end
```

Same issue different error:

```
irb(main):040:0> get_poc('mary')
6
Multiple inboxes found for Mary
1. MD-C-LAUREL-ADMIN
2. MD-E-BALTIMORE-ADMIN
3. MD-R1-CAMBRIDGE-ADMIN
4. MD-R2-BELAIR-ADMIN
5. MD-R4-LAUREL-ADMIN
6. MD-R5-HAGERSTWN-ADMIN
One of the above inboxes is the correct inbox for this ticket.
=> nil
irb(main):041:0> get_poc('paul')
21
Multiple inboxes found for Paul
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "PHILADELPHIA-RO-ADMIN":String
        from (irb):34:in `get_poc'
        from (irb):41
        from C:/Ruby23/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
irb(main):042:0>
```

How can I get the method to only count the value as one element?

Answer (score 2):

The root of the problem is that `POC['inbox'][name.downcase]` will return different objects:

1. When a single item, a `String` is returned.
2. When a list, an `Array` is returned.

In other words:

```
POC['inbox']['mary'].class
#=> Array
POC['inbox']['paul'].class
#=> String
```

`count` is defined differently for these 2 classes.

To check that there is one item, you can:

1. Check if the data is a `String` and
2. If not a `String`, check if the `count` is 1 (ie in the case that a list is used, but it only has 1 item)

The updated `if` condition would be:

```
def get_poc(name)
  data = POC['inbox'][name.downcase]

  if data.kind_of?(String) || data.count == 1
    POC['inbox'][name]
  else
    puts "Multiple inboxes found for #{name.capitalize.chomp}"
    data.each.with_index(1) do |str, i|
      puts "#{i}. #{str}"
    end
    puts 'One of the above inboxes is the correct inbox for this ticket.'
  end
end
```

Comment: The only problem is count doesn't return 1, it returns the length of the string. But why does it return a `String` not an `Array`?

Comment: `count` and `length` have a different meaning for `Strings`, so no, they won't return the expected 1. A String is returned because that is what is defined in the YAML file. A list with a single item would need to be a dashed list.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using the yml file consistently, so you don't get consistent results. If you want `Paul` to be a one element Array you need...

```
inbox:
  paul: 
    - 'PHILADELPHIA-RO-ADMIN'
 ...
```

Or you could fix it in code by changing just one line:

```
  data = [POC['inbox'][name.downcase]].flatten
```

That way you always get an Array, even if the key has just one element and the return value is String.

Comment: I was always under the impressions that an array was always returned from a `yaml`. That's awesome, thank you.